# Powershell Invoke-Item no longer works to open directories in Explorer

Tags: powershell, windows-explorer

I frequently use

```
ii .
```

in PowerShell to open the current directory in Windows Explorer. This used to work all the time, but now nothing happens.

The `Invoke-Item` cmdlet still works. Doing `ii somefile.txt` opens that file in a text editor. But directories don't work anymore.

In addition `start .` doesn't work. Using `explorer .` does work.

Running

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding {ii .} -PSHost
```

returns

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Invoke-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Invoke-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [.] to parameter [Path]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [String], parameter type [System.String[]],
collection type Array, element type [System.String], no coerceElementType
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Argument type String is not IList, treating this as scalar
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Invoke-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

Running

```
Trace-Command -Name CommandDiscovery {ii .} -PSHost
```

returns

```
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Looking up command: ii
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Alias found: ii  Invoke-Item
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Cmdlet found: Invoke-Item  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeItemCommand,
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

I guess maybe there's a file association problem or something. But I can't figure out what `Invoke-Item` is actually calling or how to change it.

How can I get this working again?

Comment: And a standard question - have you tried turning your PC off and on again? :)

Comment: @Shedal `ii $pwd` does not work.

Comment: From the traces it looks like PowerShell is working. You may be able to see why it's failing using PROCMON from Sysinternals. This would be an interesting "Case of" articles solved with Sysinternals tools.

Comment: It sure seems like you have lost the association of Folders to explorer.exe.  Try "start c:\somefolder" from a CMD prompt and see if that works. I'll bet it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very tough to figure out exactly why it might not work for you anymore, but why not use the alternative which is the same in powershell and cmd:

```
start .
```

( `explorer .` works too)

If `ii .` is important, then try restarting Powershell console and / or the computer. Also try doing `ii . -whatif` to see if you get any clue on why it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: is start usually an alias for start-process?

Comment: @Christian - Are you asking me that because I said it is same in cmd? The command that you type is same, but not what they are actually. And yes, start is alias for start-process in Powershell.

Comment: `start .` doesn't work either. `explorer .` does. If it comes down to it I can use that, but I'd prefer the consistency of `ii`.

Comment: I asked because using `start .` in powershell console give error , is like doing `start-process .`

Comment: @root45 - `start .` doesn't work?? That's weird. Shows that powershell side of things is messed up, as `explorer .` is not related to powershell and that works.

Comment: @Christian - Works for me, has always worked. `start-process .`, `start-process http://google.com` are kind of unintuitive, but they work.

Comment: `start-process http://google.com` works for me too. But no way for `start .` - start .\ works! I'm on XP now.. going test it on 2008R2..

Comment: @manojlds Agreed. Is there a way I can see what `ii .` is actually calling? I've also closed the PowerShell console and restarted. This has been an issue for a few days now.

Comment: `ii . -WhatIf` returns `What if: Performing operation "Invoke Item" on Target "Item: C:\"`. Calling `Invoke-Item C:\` also has no effect.

Comment: On 7,8 and 2008 R2 Works.. another XP hole! :)

Comment: You can try `Trace-Command -name ParameterBinding  {ii .} -PSHost` to trace the command. try also `CommandDiscovery`